# How to use es6 in TypeScript with react, webpack and babel?

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am new in front-end development, but a simple [tutorial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html) allows, it seems to me, quickly start solving problems of the subject area. The problem is ES5. It does not contain the usual and important for me tools, such as a key-value maps.

As far as I understand from the search in blogs, to solve this problem I need to translate compiled ES6-javascript to ES5-javascript using *Babel*.

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with *babel*, *webpack* and *npm*, and I could not find a working guide for such a project. Any suggestions?

Comment: why use babel and not tsc for transpilation of typescript to es5?

Comment: there are plenty of starter projects on github. SO is not the place for this kind of questions. Take this one from rangle for example https://github.com/rangle/typescript-react-redux-starter

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/

Comment: Ok. The link is what I was looking for, anyway.

Comment: One caveat. I was looking for step by step instructions, with minimum dependencies, as well as an explanation how it interacts with other tools. However, the link above is only the application template. In addition, there are a lot staff there which I do not need at the moment

Answer (score 2):

Here is my webpack json file to see how to configure babel transpiling with webpack to plain JavaScript in dist folder:  https://github.com/zuoqin/ZHReact/blob/master/webpack.config.prod.js
Inside loaders section we see babel.

And npm json file to run webpack to transpile at the start: https://github.com/zuoqin/ZHReact/blob/master/package.json

All you need after download https://github.com/zuoqin/ZHReact is to:

1. change directory to the project root
2. npm install
3. npm start build

It will run webpack and then run the server